# Plotting heatmap/locations in GeoServer & OpenLayers map from Lat/Lon data of PostGIS table

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, heat-map

I am using Geoserver, Openlayers, PostGIS for Geospatial web implemenation.

1. I have an Indian map shape files for States, Districts, Talukas. I am able to generate a map with states, districts, taluka using WMS layers in Openlayers from Geoserver.
2. However, now on top of that layers I have to show state, district, taluka with some counts & locations which I am have in PostGIS table. The PostGIS table contains state, district, latitude and longitude of the location, as well as some counts which I need to show in the map generated in (1#).

How can I implement it?

I also have to provide a Drilldown menu on the map, using filters based on statewise, districtwise data.

How do I proceed further?

Comment: It's a bit of a broad question. There is a great heapmap example, here: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/heatMap.html

Comment: Thanks John. I have provided details for ease of understanding. However, the main question is #2 point above. So, please let me knw if anyone is having idea about #2.

Comment: The advantage of openlayers is precisely working with layers, you must create a structure of layers depending on the filters you think your forms implement, once you have filtered the information can redraw the layer, remember that you can also help whith getFeatureBy (which works with the attributes of the features) http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getFeatureBy